# How to reconvert phrase with Google IME?

Tags: ime

My goal is to be able to reselect words after I've pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd> (evaluating them to kanji or kana, depending on the situation). But let's say I have typed in a word. I typed [image: two ideographic characters] instead of the intended りょうしん. Is there a way to highlight a piece of that phrase and get Google IME to re-evaluate it?

I'm trying to figure out how to use tip number 4 from [12 Japanese IME Tips](http://nihonshock.com/2010/04/12-japanese-ime-tips). Seems like I should be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to reconvert words.

Comment: Ctrl + Backspace works for me.

Comment: Please edit your question to replace the system tag "untagged" (eg by the "ime" tag). Also note that because of these 2 special characters in your question (following the "I typed ..."), because it causes some validation error if somebody tries to suggest an edit to your question (it is a not alowed character) ... they are even not allowed in comments either ...

Comment: Do you mean **Tip 2** or **Tip 4**?  **Tip 2: Reconverting** is the only one that mentions Ctrl+Backspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

By default Google's IME sets it to the 'henkan' key. Unless you're using a Japanese keyboard, you won't have that, so let's change it. Get into Google's IME properties (the exact steps to doing this will differ depending on OS, but try looking for a 'A', 'あ', or 'ア' right clicking on it and choose 'Properties'. In the general tab look for the button 'Customize' on the 'Keymap style' row.

[image]

Sort by 'Command' and change the 'Reconvert' commands to the desired setting by double clicking on the key column, and then clicking on it once more, and then you'll get a dialog that lets you set it.